# Consigo centralizar todos os Header's do meu projeto em apenas um? Linguagem C/C++

Tags: c, engenharia-de-software, projeto-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos

Boa tarde.

Estou com um problema no meu projeto em C. Fiz algumas bibliotecas e gostaria de centralizar as importações delas em apenas um header para que, quando for chamar todas, dar um `#include` apenas no header de centralização e elas serem importadas.

Por exemplo - tenho tres aquivos header's: `header1.h`,`header2.h` e `header3.h` e gostaria de centralizar eles em apenas um, `central_header.h`. Quando criar o `main.c`, ao invés de dar `#include`nos três header's eu apenas executo o `#include central_header.h`que ele já importa todos para o `main.c`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer todos os includes no seu arquivo de cabeçalho central, assim quando o main.c chamar ele, o arquivo chama os outros arquivos de cabeçalho. Exemplo:

```
#ifndef CENTRAL_H_INCLUIDA
#define CENTRAL_H_INCLUIDA

#include "teste.h"
#include "arquivo.h"

#endif
```

Quando você incluir o código acima no arquivo main.c os arquivos de cabeçalhos teste.h e arquivo.h também serão incluídos. Para evitar incluir o mesmo arquivo várias vezes não se esqueça do #ifndef em todos os arquivos .h

Comment: Sim, essas configurações me ajudaram muito mas cheguei a outra dificuldade. Fiz os includes em um Header centralizado com o #ifndef e outro Header chamou esse Header centralizado para depois o main chamar ele, porém não funcionou. Não deveria funcionar?

Comment: Deveria funcionar, mas se não está funcionando é porque há um erro em pelo menos 1 dos arquivos.  Verifique se realmente os includes estão corretos e se possível poderia mandar apenas a parte dos includes de todos os arquivos de cabeçalho para eu poder analisar melhor a situação? Vale ressaltar que do jeito que eu falei somente arquivos .h funcionam, arquivos .c não. Para compilar arquivos .c você pode incluir eles na main.c ou escrever ele na hora de compilar. Exemplo no gcc: gcc -o main main.c arquivo1.c arquivo2.c arquivon.c.